# C doesn't load info from file (fread, fwrite)

Tags: c, arrays, struct, fwrite, fread

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SLENG   50 //just a random value

typedef struct Song 
{
    char *name;
    char *nameSong;
    char *timeSong;
    int date;
}  Song;

void saveToFile(Song *x, int *songCount) //Saves info  to the binary file
{
    FILE *f = fopen("array.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    fwrite(songCount, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(x, sizeof(struct Song), (*songCount), f);
    fclose(f);
}

void readSong(Song *x, int *songCount) //Reads info fromt he file and writes it
{
    FILE *fr = fopen("array.txt", "r");
    if (fr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    printf("Songs:\n");
    fread(songCount, sizeof(int), 1, fr);
    fread(x, sizeof(struct Song), (*songCount), fr);
    for(int i=0; i < (*songCount); i++)
    {
        printf("%d. %s %s %s %d\n", (i+1), x[i].name, x[i].nameSong, x[i].timeSong, x[i].date);
    }
    fclose(fr);
}

void insertSong(Song *x, int Count) //Inserts new song into the array.
{
    printf("\nInsert name of the band:\n");
    x[Count].name=malloc(SLENG * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", x[Count].name);

    printf("Insert name of the song:\n");
    x[Count].nameSong=malloc(SLENG * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", x[Count].nameSong);

    printf("Insert length of the song:\n");
    x[Count].timeSong=malloc(SLENG * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", x[Count].timeSong);

    printf("Insert then song was created:\n");
    scanf("%d", &(x[Count].date));
    printf("\n");
}

main()
{
    int songCount, menuOption;
    Song *x=malloc(SLENG*sizeof(char)+SLENG*sizeof(char)+SLENG*sizeof(char)+sizeof(int));
    printf("1. insert song\n 2. load from file\n ");
    scanf("%d", &menuOption);
    switch(menuOption)
    {
        case(1) :
            printf("Insert how many songs do you want to input?\n");
            scanf("%d", &songCount);
            for(int i=0; i<songCount; i++)
            {
                insertSong(x, i);
            }
            saveToFile(x, &songCount);
            break;
        case(2) :
            readSong(x, &songCount);
            break;
    }
}
```

I have an assingment to write a programm which would input some data into file and could read that data from that file, the problem is probably with fwrite or fread, couse it seems to crash everytime I try to load the and write the data from file. Any ideas why is it not working properly? And can I even do it like this as it is dynamic struct array. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Pointers are specific to a single process. You can't save pointers. There's no way of loading pointers into another process, not even if it's the same program. Either use arrays, or come up with a way to [*serialize*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) the data in each structure. And yes, the pointers are all you save.

Comment: As for the matter of arrays, you allocate `SLENG` characters for each string, always and unconditionally. That's really no better than having a compile-time fixed size array.

Comment: You probably want to store the strings directly into the structure like this `typedef struct Song { char name[SLENG];  char nameSong[SLENG]; ...` rather than have pointers. BTW your comment `#define SLENG   50 //just a random value` is inappropriate; it's not _just a random value_, it's nthe length you allocate for your strings.

Comment: Lastly, your allocation for the `Song` structures is wrong. You need to be allocating `some_number * sizeof(Song)` bytes.

Comment: And another thing, there is no malloc without free. If you need to allocate memory, you need to free them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to save the structure to a file, it must only contain scalar values, not pointers into memory objects.  Modify your structure to use arrays instead of pointers:

```
typedef struct Song {
    char name[SLENG];
    char nameSong[SLENG];
    char timeSong[SLENG];
    int date;
} Song;
```

And modify the code accordingly, but note that:

- saving and reading the structures to and from a file requires opening it in binary mode `"wb"` and `"rb"`.
- it is **very misleading** to name a binary file `array.txt`.
- you do not need to pass the address of the count when writing to the file, but you need to pass the address of the array pointer when reading as you do not know yet how much memory to allocate.

Here is the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SLENG   50   // this value is used in the file format

typedef struct Song {
    char name[SLENG];
    char nameSong[SLENG];
    char timeSong[SLENG];
    int date;
} Song;

int saveToFile(Song *x, int songCount) { //Saves info  to the binary file
    FILE *f = fopen("array.bin", "wb");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    fwrite(songCount, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    int written = fwrite(x, sizeof(struct Song), songCount, f);
    fclose(f);
    return written;
}

int readSong(Song **x, int *songCount) { //Reads info from the file and writes it
    int count = 0;
    FILE *fr = fopen("array.bin", "rb");
    if (fr == NULL)  {
        printf("Error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Songs:\n");
    fread(&count, sizeof(int), 1, fr);
    *x = calloc(count, sizeof(Song));
    if (*x == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot allocate %d bytes of memory\n", count);
        fclose(fr);
        return -1;
    }
    int found = fread(*x, sizeof(struct Song), count, fr);
    for (int i = 0; i < found; i++) {
        printf("%d. %s %s %s %d\n", i + 1,
               (*x)[i].name, (*x)[i].nameSong, (*x)[i].timeSong, (*x)[i].date);
    }
    fclose(fr);
    return *songCount = found;
}

void insertSong(Song *x, int Count) { //Inserts new song into the array.
    printf("\nInsert name of the band:\n");
    scanf("%49s", x[Count].name);

    printf("Insert name of the song:\n");
    scanf("%49s", x[Count].nameSong);

    printf("Insert length of the song:\n");
    scanf("%49s", x[Count].timeSong);

    printf("Insert then song was created:\n");
    scanf("%d", &(x[Count].date));
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    int songCount, menuOption;
    Song *x = NULL;

    printf("1. insert song\n 2. load from file\n ");
    scanf("%d", &menuOption);

    switch (menuOption) {
      case 1:
        printf("Insert how many songs do you want to input?\n");
        if (scanf("%d", &songCount) == 1) {
            x = calloc(songCount, sizeof(Song));
            for (int i = 0; i < songCount; i++) {
                insertSong(x, i);
            }
            saveToFile(x, songCount);
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        readSong(&x, &songCount);
        break;
    }
    free(x);
    x = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You reversed arguments in calloc function

Comment: @Fefux: The order of arguments to `calloc()` does not have any impact, but it is indeed documented as `void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);` in the C Standard, which is inconsistent with `size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);` and `fwrite()`, although consistent with `bsearch` and `qsort`.

Comment: Yes, but it's just to be accorded with the documentation

Comment: Thanks for your help, you literaly saved me! :)